# Keep parameters in Drupal Canonical url

Tags: url, parameters, drupal-7, seo, canonical-link

How do I keep the parameters in Canonical URL while using Drupal? The setting of [current-page:url:absolute] automatically omit the parameters.

Comment: Examples like: "www.example.com?page=2" when I set the [current-page:url:absolute] in drupal meta-tags, the link given is "www.example.com"